# creating a table using unique information

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this.
[image]

And I want to create a table that looks like this using the data from the original table.
[image]

This table includes a unique combination of Firm and Symbol column and creates a third column

Basically the table has a column that includes the number of unique rows in the Firm and Symbol column of the original table I highlighted the duplicates in yellow.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Images are not preferred when you're illustrating table or data or query etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Of course you need to replace the table name placeholders.
Replace table1 with the table in the first image and replace table2 with the table name shown in the second image

```
insert into table2(firm, symbol, no_trades)
select firm, 
       symbol, 
       count(*) no_trades
    from table1
    group by firm, 
             symbol
```